# Bootstrap font/glyphicons: Failed to decode downloaded font & OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm using Laravel 5.4 & Bootstrap-sass. I'm trying to display glyph icons in a button but the icon doesn't show up.
At first I was getting a 404 error and that was because my project is located in a subfolder and it was looking in the root. So I changed `app.css` to

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1);
  src: url(/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb) format("woff2"), url(/apps/myApp
    /apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158) format("woff"), url(/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512) format("truetype"), url(/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760#glyphicons_halflingsregular) format("svg");
}
```

Now the console is throwing this error

```
Failed to decode downloaded font:  https://projects.example.com/apps/myApp/api/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1


OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

When I click on `OTS parsing error: invalid version tag` it shows this and when I hover over the html tag it says `invalid versioning tag`

[image]

I downloaded the zip from the bootstrap website and replaced the fonts and I'm still getting the same errors